# Peperomia metallica care

Tags: plant-health, plant-care

I bought this plant 2 months ago from nursery. One of its branch had this weird disease when I bought, but it's getting worse. I don't know what kind of disease is. I tried neem oil by mixing it with water and spraying it in affected areas and some homemade fungicide (ie cinnamon, Ash, turmeric and clove) and even added some neem manure for the soil but it's not stopping it from spreading. So please help me with this issue...

[image: This part of the plant's stem is infected]